# How do I make my custom WordPress meta box visible to admins only?

Tags: wordpress

I am using my `functions.php` to add a custom meta box on my posts page in the WordPress Admin Area. However, I need to make it so its only visible to admins, and not editors, contributors, etc.

What would I do to make it visible to admins only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function your_function() {
    global $current_user;
    if($current_user->roles[0] == 'administrator') {
        add_meta_box(your parameters);
        // fill in your parameters
    }
}
add_action('admin_init','your_function');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    get_currentuserinfo();
    # check if current user is admin
    if ( $current_user->wp_user_level >= 10 ) {
        # put your admin-only function here
    }
}
```

Comment: Userlevels have been deprecated since WP 2.0 - they are still supported for backwards compatibility but the role system should be used instead.

Comment: @Johannes Pille: I didn't realize user levels had been deprecated for so long! Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: They work after all. There's no need to rewrite old functions yet. However, when writing new ones it makes no sense to still keep working with userlevels. It's not like your answer is wrong. Just old.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet works for custom taxonomies.  It removes / hides a custom taxonomy meta box for all non-admins, assuming no other role has the `update_core` capability.  Similar, but opposite of the answer by @johannes-pille

```
function remove_tax_metaboxes() {
    if (!current_user_can('update_core')) {
        remove_meta_box( 'taxdiv', 'post', 'side' );
    }
}
add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'remove_tax_metaboxes' );
```

Note that the third argument of `remove_meta_box` may differ, see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box